# Is it possible to query a Neo4J db using Cypher, via the REST API, and return the URI of a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Background:

I am using a locally run Neo4J instance, (at localhost:7474), and accessing it through a Java adaptor which uses Cypher via the REST API (with Jersey), and makes data accessible to my Grails app running on the same server.

Question:

Is it possible to query a Neo4J db using Cypher, via the REST API, and return the URI of a node? Right now, I can check Neo4J server status, create nodes, populate node properties, query, and create relationships.
My problem is that my "add relationship" and traversal code requires a node URIs as input. I can query for nodes and obtain the correct JSON describing the results, but I cannot seem to get the URI locations.

Here is a simplified version of my getUserByEmail code:

```
public URI getUserByEmail( String email )
{
    System.out.println( "GETTING USER BY EMAIL [" + email + "]..." );

    String queryStr = "MATCH (user) WHERE user.nodetype=\'user\' and user.email=\'" + email + "\' RETURN user";

    WebResource webResource = client.resource( ROOT_URI + "/transaction/commit" );

    String payload = "{\"statements\" : [ {\"statement\" : \"" + queryStr + "\"} ]}";

    ClientResponse response = webResource
        .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
        .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
        .entity( payload )
        .post( ClientResponse.class );

    String responseStr = response.getEntity( String.class );
    URI responseLocation = response.getLocation();

    System.out.println( "RESPONSE STRING: " + responseStr );
    System.out.println( "GOT USER AT: [" + responseLocation + "]" );

    return responseLocation;
}
```

The JSON results come back fine and reflect what is in the graph db. The location, however, is always null.

The "add relationship" code that I am using works, as long as I have the URI to the start node. The code I have is based on the addRelationship() code that lives here:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.1.6/community/server-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/server/CreateSimpleGraph.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON results, the `self` property value for each "user" will be its URI.

[In this example,](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-create-multiple-nodes-with-properties) the response has 2 "n" nodes, and the `self` property value of each is its URI.

[Here is an example](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-execute-statements-in-an-open-transaction-in-rest-format-for-the-return) of how to get the transactional endpoint (which is normally less verbose than the legacy endpoint) to also return the `self` property.

Comment: That example is for doing a create. I am interested in a query to find a node. When I execute such a query, I do not get back all the extensive data that the example shows. I just get the domain-level data that I created. Maybe I need to use the endpoint that the example does, instead of the transactional cypher endpoint?

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it will solve my problem. Will try it out tonight. Just as a clarification, does the example also work for a MATCH, or just a CREATE statement?

Comment: Yes. The only thing that matters is what the `RETURN` clause looks like.

Answer (score 2):

You can in your case create the node uri yourself by just appending the node internal id to the following url :

http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/your-123-id

maybe you want to set the scheme, host and database port in a configuration file to not do hardcode changes when changing the database location.

Comment: Where do I get the internal id? All I get back in the JSON response is the actual data I created in the node.

Comment: match (n) return id(n)